# Groovy : Stuck in designing DSL with variable arguments

Tags: groovy, dsl

i need to design a DSL( Domain Specific Language) using groovy chain command.

I have following Employee Database

```
 Name     Age    Date-Of-Joining    Salary
 Test     24     12-aug-2015        6000$
```

I need to create a DSL which is like :-

**update name to "test1" , age to "26 "** and so on.

Problem is :- **fields that can be updated are user-defined ie he/she can choose , which columns will be updated and its dynamic .**

So :- **update salary to "7000$" should also work.**

Is it possible to create such dynamic dsl ? If so please provide some brief information ,in order to proceed with such design

I have already developed the backend system which will update value.

I am not getting how to get the values from this dynamic dsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DSL you should have some information about which employee record should have been updated (e.g. providing the primary key in the employee table).

The dynamism you would like to have in your DSL is definitely possible in Groovy. See this small example as a starting point (this example does not use a database to keep it simple):

```
class Employee 
{
    String name
    int age
    int salary

    public String toString()
    {
        "name=${name}, age=${age}, salary=${salary}\$"
    }

    def update(String attributeName)
    {
        ['to': { Object value ->
            this[attributeName] = value
            ['and': { String nextAttrName ->
                update(nextAttrName)
            }]
        }]
    }
}

Employee emp = new Employee(name: 'Test', age: 24, salary: 6000)
println emp // name=Test, age=24, salary=6000$

emp.with
{
    update 'name' to 'John'
    println emp // name=John, age=24, salary=6000$

    update 'salary' to 7000
    println emp // name=John, age=24, salary=7000$

    update 'name' to 'Michael' and 'age' to 48
    println emp // name=Michael, age=48, salary=7000$
}
```

Your DSL will be executable code so you will not 'extract' the values but the DSL will call your backend methods.

There is a very good presentation about creating DSLs in Groovy: [Creating Groovy DSLs that Developers Can Actually Use](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/groovy-dsl-mars). This presentation teaches a lot about DSL internals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have updated the question . If i call DSL by the way my i want , this its giving null values . if i use with{} closure then only its working. How can i get values without using with closure?

Comment: @user2332505 your update contains only a part of your code; you should post a 'runnable' snippet to demonstrate the problem

Comment: thanks alot. I was making a minor mistake. Its working now